# How to execute command for go group character in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to execute the command goGroupLeftCtrl in codemirror and it is not working,

Other commands like goLineUp is working.

```
editor.execCommand('goGroupLeftCtrl');
```

The cursor should move to left of the word. Do I need any special addons?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the problem by using a different technique. Instead of using execCommand, I used keydown functionality with ctrlKey